# Windows 7 equivalent of "Add-WindowsFeature"

Tags: iis, windows-7

I'm wanting to script the "Turn Windows Features On or Off" functionality for my development group so that we'll have a means of ensuring that everyone is running on the same configurations.  I know that you can do this in Win Server 2008, but in Windows 7 it appears that the "Add-WindowsFeature" cmdlet isn't available.  I've also read that it is possible using DISM.exe, but I'm afraid to use this without any prior experience because it seems risky.

It doesn't necessarily have to be scripting.  Windows Features is just one of serveral configurations that developers are responsible for modifying personally.  It would also be nice to ensure (for example) that IIS and certain services are configured properly on a given developer's machine.  If there's a larger scale tool that could give us this functionality, I would be interested in that too.  I'm just hesitant of DISM because I don't know it and it seems to change the image files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

List available features:

`dism /Online  /Get-Features`

Enable feature:

`dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:featureA`

Disable feature:

`dism /Online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:featureB`

Using `dism` is no more/less risky that accessing `appwiz.cpl` as an administrator.

**re-edit**

Here's a script I've actually *tried* before posting. It will iterate available features and list their *Feature Name* as well as *Display Name* -- This is what appears in `appwiz.cpl`.  I am *still* sure someone will post an elegant one-liner that puts this to shame:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3,*" %%a in (`dism /Online /Get-Features ^| find /i "name"`) do (
    dism /Online /Get-FeatureInfo /FeatureName:"%%b" | find /i "name"
)
```

Comment: Thanks jscott, but Get-Features doesn't seem to give me the same set of features as actually opening "Windows Features".  Specifically, I do not see "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1" in the Get-Features results.

Comment: @L.Moser: Not all features are named idential to the listing in `appwiz.cpl`.  You're looking for `NetFx3`, case-sensitive...  To turn it on `dism /Online  /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3`

Comment: Actually, The two child nodes for "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1" are "WCF HTTP Activation" and "WCF Non-HTTP Activation".  These entries are available in Get-Features.  Maybe I just missed something.

Thanks again jscott, I think I have a better idea of how this works now.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out the mapping from "Get-Features" to "Windows Features"?

Comment: @L.Moser, My method for figuring out some of the more obscure mappings is to just add the feature on a test system and then see what is enabled.  It helps if you send the output of `Dism /online /Get-Features` before and after you enable the feature to text files.  Then you can use a diff utility.

Comment: The Get-Feature switch used in these DISM statements maps to the Get-WindowsOptionalFeature powershell cmdlet.  The Get-WindowsFeature cmdlet actually provides information on server roles and features, which is why it doesnt work on anything other than Windows 2012.  Really the DISM command should be Get-OptionalFeatures.  Because I actually need to use DISM to get the server roles and features, not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

DISM is what you're looking for.  You use the /online option to target the running OS rather than an offline image.  This is how you add and remove windows roles and features in Server Core.